# Is there a quick way to approximate a logarithm in Nernst equation?

Tags: acid-base, electrochemistry, equilibrium

The problem is as follows:

> In a galvanic cell the cathode is an $Ag^{+}(1.00\,M)/Ag_{(s)}$
>   half-cell. The anode is a standard hydrogen electrode immersed in a
>   buffer solution containing $0.10\,M$ benzoic acid $(C_6H_5COOH)$ and
>   $0.050\,M$ of sodium benzoate $(C_6H_5COO^{-}Na^{+})$. The measured
>   cell voltage is $1.030\,V$. What is the $pK_a$ of benzoic acid?.

What I did to solve this problem was to find the potential for the cell involving the standard hydrogen electrode. At first I was confused because there are three "elements" featured in the problem. One being the silver electrode, the other the standard hydrogen electrode and the other a buffer solution, so I didn't know how to proceed from there.

Then I noticed that to get the constant of equilibrium I only require the concentration of $[H^{+}]$ ions as,

$K_a=\frac{[C_6H_5COO^{-}][H^{+}]}{[C_6H_5COOH]}$

Therefore to obtain those protons I did this:

The half equations in the cell are:

$\begin{array}{cc}
Ag^{+}+1e^{-}\rightarrow Ag_{(s)}&E^{0}=0.7999\,V\\
H^{+}+1e^{-}\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}H_{2(g)}&E^{0}=0.0000\,V\\
\end{array}$

Hence the overall reaction for this process would be:

$E^{0}_{cell}=E_{cathode}-E_{anode}=0.7999-0.0000=0.7999\,V$

Which is for:

$Ag^{+}+\frac{1}{2}H_{2}+\rightarrow Ag_{(s)} + H^{+}$

Hence:

$E_{cell}=E^{0}-\frac{0.0592}{n}\log\frac{[H^{+}]}{[Ag^{+}]p^{\frac{1}{2}}_{H_{2(g)}}}$

Since it indicates that the cell potential is $1.030\,V$ then:

$1.030=0.7999-\frac{0.0592}{1}\log\frac{[H^{+}]}{[1](1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

Solving this I'm getting:

$[H^{+}]=0.000125306\,M$

Now all that's left is to plug in this value in the equation to get the equilibrium constant:

$K_a=\frac{[C_6H_5COO^{-}][H^{+}]}{[C_6H_5COOH]}$

$[C_6H_5COO^{-}]=0.05\,M$ and $[C_6H_5COOH]=0.1\,M$

Hence:

$K_a=\frac{(0.05)(1.25306\times 10^{-4})}{(0.1)}=6.2653\times 10^{-5}$

Therefore the $pKa$ of benzoic acid would be:

$pKa=-\log Ka=-\log\left(6.2653\times 10^{-5}\right)=4.20306$

Which does seem to be within the value of benzoic acid which I have on different references. But the problem with this method it is that it required the use of logarithm.

Given this situation, does it exist an approximation or anything that can be done right of the bat to get an idea where that value would be?. Does it exist another method which I could use?.

Comment: You can involve Czebysev orthogonal polynomial serie as logarithm approximation.. :-)

Comment: How did you come to  $[\ce{C6H5COO-}]=[\ce{H+}]=\pu{0.05 M}$ ?  It is approximately valid for the acid solution, but not for the solution of the acid and its salt. Rather  $[\ce{C6H5COO-}]=[\ce{H+}]+[\ce{Na+}=[\ce{H+}]+\pu{0.05 M}$

Comment: @Poutnik, good answer! Use an orthogonal polynomial if you don't like logs or Taylor series expansion. The question is why avoid logs to begin with?

Comment: @M. Farooq  I remember the golden age of the "true programmers", 8bit computers and Z80 Assembler language. I owned the commented source code of ROM content of the legendary Sinclair ZX-Spectrum and noticed Czebyshev orthogonal polynomials ( COP ) were the way how it approximated functions like EXP, LN, SIN and ArcTan. For those not familiar, A polynomial function based on COPs minimizes the maximal approximation error for given function and an approximating polynomial based on them, for the given polynomial order.

Comment: 0

@Chris Steinbeck Bell You may use few useful points for rough numerical approximation: Log ( A . 10^N ) = Log ( A ) + N, where A is +1.0 .. +10. Log(1)=0 Log(2)~=0.30 Log(3)~=0.48 Log(5)~=0.70 Log(10)=1

Comment: @Poutnick I am sorry I made a mistake in the typing. It should had been only the concentration of the salt $C_{6}H_{5}COO^{-}$ equal to $0.05\,M$  As you can see in the following steps I did calculated the $[H^+]$ from the cell reaction from silver and the SHE. Are we okay with this?. By the way I am aware of the Chebyshev's polynomials but I don't have enough experience with them to use them as an approximation for logarithm function. Can this be done by hand?

Comment: @M.Farooq The thing is what if I don't have access to a calculator and I must find the result or an approximation to a reasonable accuracy. Can this be achieved without using a logarithm?. The previous comments mentioned a golden age of programming. But as already mentioned, what if I dont have access to such technology? By the way I am familiar with the golden age of programming but for me the only language which made me feel comfortable was BASIC.

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks for those log shortcuts. It seems than other than the hat rule for logarithms and change of base and product or division and memorizing the values for some integers there isnt much that can be done, which of course would be to use the polynomials you mentioned.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell, I am not a programmer either, but calculator is in eveyone's reach.  I have studied in a time in school which taught us how to use printed tables to calculate log. It was fun looking up mantissa and characteristics. Anyway, you can use Taylor series expansion https://www.efunda.com/math/taylor_series/logarithmic.cfm to approximate log function.

Comment: Everybody, who can post to Chemistry SE site, has available plenty of free software based calculators. For Windows, Linux, Android. Not sure about Mac and iPhone, but I bet there as well. There are online web based calculators as well.

Comment: @M. Farooq Taylor serie for logarithm has quite slow convergence.

Comment: I still do not understand why the original poster is avoiding a log. Certainly, he wishes to avoid log "button" on a calculator, so go for the slow but algebraic version.

Comment: @M.Farooq I don't know if you are getting my idea. What I intended to ask is if there was a method to solve these kinds of problems which involve logarithms by inspection or by a rough and still reasonable approximation with the least steps. Something you can do perhaps mentally or with short lines by hand. Needless to say that there are plenty of tools, but I'm aiming at an abreviated method of computation. By the way I don't have a personal aversion to calculators or anything along those lines, but rather as a recommendation of what to do when *for some reason* a calculator isn't available.

Comment: @M.Farooq And this extends to a cell phone or whatsoever. But sure It seems that the only methods mentioned are either Taylor's expansion, or memorization of some log values, or having to consult with a table. Are we right on this?.

Comment: @Poutnik It might not seem obvious but of course you can use any free tool available when you're in front of a computer. But the intention of this question was what approach can be recommended when **is not** available. And as I mentioned in the lines from above, the best is to either memorize values or consult with a table or if you have more space and time, to try out Taylor expansion. But in all and all Nernst equation requires a logarithm and you can't avoid this unless the concentrations are near to the values of the base either as a base 10 logarithm or an euler number log if you go

Comment: @Poutnik by the natural logarithm route, which of course was already simplified by using the $\frac{0.0592}{n}$. I'm not sure if this way was I better understood. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comments it seems that you are looking for an approximation of a log. I wish you clarified that in the main question without mentioning calculators. It seemed you just wanted to avoid a calculator for some unknown reasons. As Poutnik states, anyone who can post here, will certainly have access to computers and hence the ability to calculate logs.

A first-hand approximation is $ln (1+x)$= $x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+...$

Also see https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-calculate-ln-x-without-using-a-calculator

Use you use a simple ln to log conversion factor in the Nernst equation.

So whatever number you get after dividing the concentrations, subtract "one" from it. This is your $x$. Since you are assuming that a calculator or computer is not available, all you need is a paper an pencil to evaluate the right hand side.

No need to memorize anything for logs.

If you can afford a slide rule, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule, it can also help as a mechanical calculator. I never used them but Youtube has videos on it.

Comment: @M.Farroq As Poutnik's mentioned in the end this depends on how far are you going with the approximation as the function has slow convergence?. The thing here is that you **can** use a computer or any technological tool but if **later** you cannot have access to it **for some reason** does it exist another way to aleviate this caveat?. From your answer its a yes. By the way **i do have a japanese slide rule**, but the thing here was to do a quick calculation **on the go** that you can do in few minutes or something without compromising the answer too much.

Comment: But as I indicated above, galvanic cells in non standard conditions **must** require resort to Nernst equation and solely to that reason one way or another you might have to deal with them. If you are allowed to modify or set the experiment or whatsoever, perhaps the best choice without avoiding much fuss is to select concentrations which cancel or simplify the logarithm. :)

Comment: At least give Taylor series a try. I do understand your point now. Sorry there is no simple short cut.

Comment: It would benefit the answer to note that concentration of $[H^{+}]$ in these cases are found from SHE (standard hydrogen electrode) and any other electrodes which this is interacting. Am I right with this?.

Comment: No, the hydrogen ion concentration is determined via pH of each half cell. What I do, is that I apply Nernst equation on individual half cells rather write the entire cell reaction for one Nernst equation.

Comment: In my calculations I did used the SHE to get the concentration of $[H^{+}]$ ions. Applying the Nernst equation to individual half cells in the end is subtracted cathode minus the anode and those logarithms will multiply and end up as a fraction, which would account for the same as adding the two half reactions. In the end it ends the same. **But** yes to get the $pH$ depends on the concentration of those ions for each half cell. Does my approach exhibit any flaw in this question?. Sorry, I just want to get my concepts correct!.

Comment: I think your concepts are alright.

Comment: Note that the mentioned Taylor serie is for the natural logarithm, not decadic logarithm. Be aware that depending on context and domain customs, natural logarithm is ln or log, decadic log or log10.

Comment: About Czebyshev approximation of ln ( 1 + x ), see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447075/chebyshev-expansion-of-log1-x

Answer (score 2):

[Padé Approximation for ln(1+x)](http://www.nezumi.demon.co.uk/consult/logx.htm) provides very interesting trade off between simplicity and accuracy ( See also [Wikipedia - Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) ):

> $$P\{ \ln( 1+x ) \} = \frac{x(6+x)}{6+4x}$$
>
> $\ln(1) = 0$, $\ln(2) = 0.7$,  $e_\mathrm{max} = 0.00685$, $e_\mathrm{max, rel} \lt 1\% $, $e_\mathrm{RMS} = 0.00258$
>
> This is already a good and fast approximation to $\ln(1+x)$ and in many applications like realtime displays can be used as a basis for logarithmic scaling with a few minor modifications for integer arithmetic.
>
> Where greater accuracy is required the expression can be optimised by least squares fitting of the coefficients over the range 0-1. This yields:
>
> $$p'\{ \ln( 1+x ) \} = \frac{x \cdot (6 + 0.7662\cdot x)}{5.9897 + 3.7658 \cdot x}$$
>
> $\ln(1) = 0$, $\ln(2) = 0.69358$, $e_\mathrm{max} = 4.3E-4$, $e_\mathrm{max, rel} \lt 0.1\% $, $e_\mathrm{RMS} = 1.5E-4$
>
> This is about as good as you can get with this simple formula, and these coefficients may be scaled up to suitable integers for use.
>
> Much higher accuracy is possible by starting from a better series:
>
> Define: $y = x/(2+x)$,  then $\ln{ \frac{1+y}{1-y} } = 2y + 2y^3/3 + 2y^5/5 + ... $
>
> $\ln(1) = 0$, $\ln(2) = 0.69300$, $e_\mathrm{max} = -0.00014$
>
> From which the Pade approximation yields:
>
> $$P\{ \ln \frac{1+y}{1-y} \} = \frac{2y*(15 - 4y^2 )}{15 - 9y^2}$$
>
> $\ln(1) = 0$, $\ln(2) = 0.693122 $, $e_\mathrm{max} = -0.000025$
>
> Again this expression can also have its coefficients tweaked to improve accuracy over a narrow range still further.